TypeScript Error with Event Callback Types
I'm encountering a TypeScript error while trying to implement a binding function for an event map. I have defined an eventForMap type with various event types, each containing a callback function with specific signatures.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
export type eventTypeCall = (p: eventCallOpt) => void;

export type eventForMap = {
  mouseMove: { id: string; callback: eventTypeCall }[]
  leftClick: { id: string; callback: eventTypeCall }[]
  dbClick: { id: string; callback: eventTypeCall }[]
  rightClick: { id: string; callback: eventTypeCall }[]
  mouseDown: { id: string; callback: eventTypeCall }[]
  mouseUp: { id: string; callback: eventTypeCall }[]
  mousewheel: { id: string; callback: () => void }[]
  moveStart: { id: string; callback: () => void }[]
  moving: { id: string; callback: () => void }[]
};

bindEventForMap<K extends keyof eventForMap>(
  eventType: K,
  callback: eventForMap[K][number]['callback']
) {
  const id = generateUUID();
  this.eventForMap[eventType].push({ id, callback });
}

Error Messages:
Cannot assign type “eventTypeCall | (() => void)” to type “() => void”.
Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.
Question:
How can I resolve these type errors when trying to use different callback types in my event map?
don't use 'as',TypeScript Error with Event Callback Types

• Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without references to undeclared types or values. Right now my IDE is unhappy with eventCallOpt and generateUUID and this, among other things. It makes it hard to get started. • Assuming I guessed correctly what you're doing, this only works in TS if you refactor to use the technique from ms/TS#47109, shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?
